# docker : commit doesn't seem to persist changes by the passwd command

Tags: docker

```
docker run -i -t dhrp/sshd /bin/bash
root@f123d1d12d>passwd
```

...change the password.

In another shell:

```
docker commit f123d1d12d max/sshd
fbf0b19e284f
max@max-ubuntu:~$ docker images
max/sshd            latest         fbf0b19e284f    13 seconds ago      21.12 kB
```

Then I start the container:

```
docker  run -d -p 22 max/sshd /usr/sbin/sshd -D
docker ps 

ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
440871de534f        dhrp/sshd:latest    /bin/bash           34 seconds ago      Up 34 seconds               
49164->22
```

Then I try to login:

```
root@localhost 49164
```

Using the password "commited" earlyer, and it fails (invalid passwd or username)...

To make sure the commit is done properly I did:

```
echo 123 > test
```

...inside the container before the commit.

And then run:

```
>docker  run  max/sshd cat test
>123
```

So the commit is doing something, just not persisting the passwd command...

Versions:

```
max@max-ubuntu:~$ docker version
Client version: 0.5.0
Server version: 0.5.0
Go version: go1.1
```

And dhrp/sshd is whatever happens to be in the docker index....

Comment: Try with `docker push` to save docker container changes, not `docker commit` to save images.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what the problem was :

Not invoking the ssh client properly :

root@localhost 49164

should have been :

root@localhost -p 49164

I'll close the question because it will just add noise....

Comment: Sounds like the right thing to do, but why didn't you close it after all ?